# How to call javascript function in mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3

I want to call a function in mongodb query. Is there any way to do such thing or is there any other way to do that

Example:

```js
const imageUrl = function(imageName) {
  const urlParams = {Bucket: 's3-bucket/uploads', Key: imageName};
  s3bucket.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, async function (err, url) {
    console.log('imageUrl', url);
  });
}

const feedTest = await Feed.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      feedImage: imageUrl(feedImage),
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted in case if it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute a function as part of mongo query, but you can pass the result there. The problem is that you would need to make your query inside of the callback. But that can be managed with promises and async/await:

```
const imageUrl = function(imageName) {
    const urlParams = {Bucket: 's3-bucket/uploads', Key: imageName};
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3bucket.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, (err, url) => {
            if (err) {
               reject(err)
            } else {
               resolve(url)
            }
        })
     })
}

const feedTest = await Feed.aggregate([ {
    $project:{
        _id: 1,
        feedImage: await imageUrl(feedImage),
    }
}
```